# How to set the principal of a MessageDriven bean using annotations?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, glassfish-4, message-driven-bean

I'm running on glassfish v4 and I use a messagedriven bean. Currently I'm defining the principal under which the bean runs in the `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` like:

```
<enterprise-beans>
  <ejb>
    <ejb-name>MessageConsumerBean</ejb-name>
    <principal>
      <name>MDBPrincipal</name>
    </principal>
```

Is it possible to do the same using just annotations e.g. `@MessageDriven`?

Comment: Did you tried the @RunAs annotation? It won't set the caller principal but will allow you to run protected methods.

Comment: @nomoa yes. But as you said, it won't set the Principal.

Comment: Well, I have no other clue except digging into GF source code for an obscure @ActivationConfigProperty. It's a known limitation of MDB (see Programming Restrictions Applying to MDBs at http://underpop.online.fr/j/java/expert-one-on-one-j2ee-design-and-development/lib0066.html)

Comment: @nomoa So is it that MDBs don't have a Principal by design? If so that would be an answer.

Comment: Principal is not propagated from client (message sender) to MDB by design. It's why there is no Principal in MDB. If MDB is need to be granted a specific role then RunAs is OK. But if you need Principal for some application logic I'm afraid there's only platform dependent solution like RunAsPrincipal (JBoss) or glassfish-ejb-jar.xml in your case (can't find any glassfish custom annotations).

Comment: @nomoa if you can put this as an answer and add some official docu(maybe ejb/mdb spec) the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://java.net/downloads/ejb-spec/mdb.no-method.interface.pdf section 5.4.14 page 133 a Principal **may** be propagated in the security context but details are not governed by the EJB spec. In other words it's a platform dependent feature.

One can use @RunAs If MDB need to be granted a specific role to run some protected @RolesAllowed method.

If you need Principal for some application logic I'm afraid there's only platform dependent solution like RunAsPrincipal (JBoss) or glassfish-ejb-jar.xml in your case.